# Make new directory automatically in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi can someone help me to create a right path for my files in python? My path must be exported/files/{t}/{y}/filename.
If i put in dir variable {y} on the end it won't work for some reason.
My code is

```
tables=["table1","table2"]
years=["2010","2020"]
months=[1,2,3,4...12]
for t in tables:
     for y in years:
           for m in months:
                dir=(f"exported/files/{t}")
                os.mkdir(dir)
                sqlcode="select * from {t} where some condition..."
                filename= (f"{t}_{y}_{m}.sql")
                with open(os.path.join(dir,filename_),"w") as writer:
                     writer.write(sqlcode)
```

Comment: you could use [os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) and call it with `exist_ok=True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Path from pathlib :

```
from pathlib import Path



tables=["table1","table2"]
years=["2010","2020"]
months=[1,2,3,4...12]
for t in tables:
     for y in years:
           for m in months:
                full_path = f"exported/files/{t}"
                Path(full_path ).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
                sqlcode="select * from {t} where some condition..."
                filename= (f"{t}_{y}_{m}.sql")
                with open(os.path.join(full_path ,filename),"w") as writer:
                     writer.write(sqlcode)
```

Note: avoid using the keyword dir as it is saved keyword.

Comment: Nice, thank you for your answer. I still don't get it why just putting {y} in the dir variable didn't work.

Comment: because there is nested dirs.. its not creating a nested dirs unless specified... the solution I gave you cover many use cases///

Comment: Ok one more upgrade question. Lets assume that i will have sql table1 with dates from 2019 till 2020, but i will have also a table table1_2018. How to go through table 1 just for 2019 and 2020 and in table1_2018 just with 2018.

Comment: you better open a different question for that, tbh i dont use sql...

Answer (score 1):

you should use os.makedirs() method instead of os.mkdir() method
beacuse mkdir() can create a single sub-directory but makedirs() used to create branches
also put exist_ok=True in os.makedirs() method
and remove underscore from filename_ in line 11

should look like this:

```
tables=["table1","table2"]
years=["2010","2020"]
months=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
for t in tables:
     for y in years:
           for m in months:
                dir=(f"exported/files/{t}")
                os.makedirs(dir, exist_ok=True)
                sqlcode="select * from {t} where some condition..."
                filename= (f"{t}_{y}_{m}.sql")
                with open(os.path.join(dir,filename),"w") as writer:
                     writer.write(sqlcode)
```